# Passing data from fragment to fragment within a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager activity which will contain different fragments

I want to pass data from Fragment 1 to Fragment 2, Fragment 2 to Fragment 3, and so forth

Now I understand there is a way to do it by sending data back to the Activity and then passing it onto the next fragment by making a custom interface in the fragment and implementing them on the activity, but is there a way to do it so that the data is passed directly?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: depends on PagerAdapter implementation the FragmentX (where X != 1) may not yet exists when Fragment1 is visible ...

Comment: No, i have set it to that when Fragment1 is visible, all other fragments are not visible. If I set it so that if Fragment1 is visible and Fragment2 and Fragment0 will also be visible, will that be easier to do?

Comment: Some of your options are : the interface you mentioned, content provider, sharedpreferences, some sort of SQL table, singleton.

Comment: Ah. Sharedpreferences. I forgot about that. Thank you very much!